The Motivation of Axioms for Homology
I am reading Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher and I'm curious about the motivation of axioms for singular homology.

Singular homology is easy to be defined and understood,so I think singular homology's too specific to be axiomatized.
The axioms look complicated and ugly,even less trivial than the
definition of singular homology.
The axioms aren't universal
since it's not effective for homology algebra of module categories or Abelian categories.

This is why I wonder why mathematicians introduce it.

If you prove properties from the axioms, then you know they hold for any homology theory that follows the axioms.


is very unclear.


It's hard to compute much of anything directly using singular homology: you're typically dealing with Abelian groups of uncountable cardinality. You typically use the axioms (which are theorems for singular homology), or you define some cell structure and use cellular or simplicial homology, which can be proved to be equivalent to singular homology using the axioms. It's reassuring that we can always do this (edit: for spaces homotopy equivalent to a CW complex); we don't lose anything by just using the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. The axioms feel most helpful when dealing with a topological space that doesn't come with a nice or obvious cell decomposition.
Another thing to mention is that a singular cubical homology can be defined using singular cubes $[0,1]^n \to X$ instead of simplices. The two theories coincide on nice spaces (actually for all spaces), as they both satisfy the axioms. So it's also reassuring that there's nothing essentially "simplex-based" about homology; it's somehow more natural than that.
